# DevExpress: How do I develop for it without a license?

Tags: devexpress

I am a freelance dev.. a customer wants me to work with DevExpress. How does that work? I cannot afford a license for it. I could download the trial for 30 days.. but for a more long term and "proper" solution.. how is this usually done? Do I need to acquire the license from my client? He says previous developers have coded for him without a license but he doesn't know how. Please someone provide some clarification for me.

**UPDATE**

I should have clarified: The client has bought DevExpress but tells me he doesn't have any licenses at current to give to me.. because they are being used by other devs. So I guess after I write the app, he will build it and not have the annoying messages. I just want to be able to develop for it..that's all. Is it possible or do I need to tell him to get another license for me?

Comment: Ask your customer to provide you with the license.

Comment: AFAIK, the client must assign a license for you for a period you need to accomplish the task, if you do not have own license. Otherwise you violate the license: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/EULAs/NetComponents.xml

Comment: 1) after 30 days trial finished, you can take your time back 30 days or more.
2) some components of DevExpress doesnt require license and they are free. But I dont remember which components. 
3) If someone installed licensed DX to Virtual Machine, then you can use that VM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. You may be able to do the development, but you won't be able to redistribute the controls. Well - you *could* but last time I checked they had licencing messages popping up if you hadn't registered the control suite before shipping your product. So it wouldn't be a good look.

You may not be able to afford the whole suite, so maybe just buy a couple of the items from the suite. They are developers too and need to feed their children, so they do need to make some money.

Your alternative is to either write controls from scratch, or use the various free components you can find on the net.

Comment: I should have clarified: The client has bought DevExpress but tells me he doesn't have any licenses at current to give to me.. because they are being used by other devs. So I guess after I write the app, he will build it and not have the annoying messages. I just want to be able to develop for it..that's all. Is it possible or do I need to tell him to get another license for me?

Comment: So, if I use the 30 days trial... basically I can keep using it beyond that, but on my machine it will give annoying messages? I can live with that as long as the customer can build it against a licensed version when I am finished developing for it. Do you know if that is the case?

Comment: @Matt It has been a while since I used them unregisterd (it was by accident on a build machine, we had the licences available). From memory you will simply get nags. If the client will rebuild against a licenced suite that is great just make sure you develop against the same version. You should forget that I mentioned using virtual machines to do your development on because I never mentioned that at all ;) They are a good component suite, it's worth having a legit copy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And yes, I would like a full copy.. but for $900, that'll have to wait...  :)

Answer (score 8):

There is a file in your project called Licenses.licx, if you empty the file, turn all your references to copy local = true, then the splash will permanently disappear until you modify the code with newer controls from DevExpress.

Comment: This possibly only works if you don't open the designer, in my case it was a nuget package that is referenced by the project that requires devexpress. That package is fully licensed by the dev server so your solution worked fine

Comment: This worked for me, except I also updated the references in .csproj to remove the Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken and processorArchitecture, and used `HintPath` instead of "copy local".
Example:  `<Reference Include="DevExpress.Data.v15.1"><HintPath>..\..\DevExBin_15.1.2\DevExpress.Data.v15.1.dll</HintPath></Reference>`
I didn't need to open the designer on any form, just re-build targeting a newer version of .NET framework, and add new code unrelated to DevExpress controls.

Answer (score 5):

We use DevExpress controls in our shop.  We're a a small team of devs, only three people.  So the price difference between 1 license vs. 2 or 3 is a big deal for us.  Our development structure leads to only one of us doing programming wotj dev express controls, while the other devs only need to have the package and controls installed for compilation, etc.  Dev Express gave us permission to operate in this capacity, if you ask them, they might be willing to work with your situation.

All in all, I've found their very nice people.